# Cannot get ImageResizer to resize my Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, thumbnails, imageresizer

I've just started using ImageResizer to create thumbnails for my images using the code from their website below.

```
private void CreateThumbnail()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //Define the versions to generate
    versions.Add("_thumb", "width=100&height=100&crop=auto&format=jpg"); //Crop to square thumbnail
    versions.Add("_medium", "maxwidth=100&maxheight=100&format=jpg"); //Fit inside 400x400 area, jpeg
    versions.Add("_large", "maxwidth=1900&maxheight=1900&format=jpg"); //Fit inside 1900x1200 area

    //Loop through each uploaded file
    foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
        if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; //Skip unused file controls.

        //Get the physical path for the uploads folder and make sure it exists
        string uploadFolder = MapPath("~/Images");
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

        //Generate each version
        foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
        {
            //Generate a filename (GUIDs are best).
            string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "AssetID" + suffix);

            //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
            fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, fileName, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true);                
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I apply this code to a Pdf it crashes with the error 'File may be corrupted, empty, or may contain a PNG image with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.'
What changes do I need to make to enable sizing a Pdf? I've gone through their documentation and although it seems that it will create a Thumbnail from a Pdf, the examples are all using images.

This is the list of Plugins including PdfRenderer

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through and done the setup required in http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/pdfrenderer?

Have you opened the PDF with a PDF renderer like Adobe Acrobat to see if the PDF is really corrupt? Acrobat has a preflight tool built in that will check if the PDF has any errors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PdfiumRenderer or PdfRenderer plugin (whichever you chose) is not installed. Thus, the primary decoder is failing to decode the image.

You must install a PDF plugin for this to work.

PdfiumRenderer is the better of the two.

See http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/pdfiumrenderer

Comment: I've amended my text above to include a copy of the NuGet plugin screen which shows I have already added PdfRenderer

Comment: That is not sufficient. You must register it per the instructions.

Comment: Show the self-diagnostics page.

Comment: Diagnostics page - The thread 0x7124 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'ImageResizer.ImageCorruptedException' occurred in ImageResizer.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/32/ROOT-1-131027043435992643): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
The thread 0xc390 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Comment: I cannot find anything about registering Pdfrenderer, where can I find it or better still how do I do it?

Comment: I followed the instructions again including add the reference and GSDll.dll and it now works. Thanks for your help